# Error adding cart item to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm writing a commerce application and am running into a frustrating error that doesn't tell me what the actual error is.

[image: Error Message Details]

This is the code that is being run

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int product_ID)
{
    if (db.Products.Any(product => product.Product_ID == product_ID))
    {
        //var successfulAddToCart = false;
        var cartItem = new Cart();

       // cartItem.CartID = Guid.NewGuid();

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var Customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.Email == User.Identity.Name);
            cartItem.Customer = Customer;
            cartItem.CustomerID = Customer.Customer_ID;
        }                    
        else//not logged in, need to remember them somehow
        {
            // add a cookie for a guest user so we can save their cart for some time.
            var CartCookie = new HttpCookie("Cart", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            CartCookie.Expires.AddDays(2);
            Request.Cookies.Add(CartCookie);
            cartItem.Customer = new Customer();
            cartItem.CustomerID = null;
        }

        //obviously not checked out since we just added to cart
        cartItem.IsCheckedOut = false;
        cartItem.Quantity = 1;
        //one to one with product, so grab the first sku you find.
        var Sku = db.SKU_Table.SingleOrDefault(sku => sku.Product_ID == product_ID);
        cartItem.Sku = Sku;
        cartItem.SkuID = Sku.SKU_ID;
        //if everything is okay, save the changes to the database
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Cart.Add(cartItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        //return a content string that displays success or failure
        return Content("Add to cart was successful");
    }
    return Content("Add to cart was not successful");//unsuccessful add 
}
```

Now as far as I can tell, my model is perfectly valid and I don't know what the source of the issue is. I can post values of the cart item object if that will be helpful. The error message doesn't really help and I don't see anything wrong with my modelstate, especially since it's passing.

Here is the cart model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SeniorProjectMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Cart")]
    public class Cart
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid CartID { get; set; }
        public int SkuID { get; set; }
        public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; } 
        public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public bool IsCheckedOut { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: *The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.*....check in your `else` this line of code `cartItem.CustomerID = null;`...change it for something like `cartItem.CustomerID = 0;` and see if it works :)

Comment: I've tried that and that field is not required in the database as it's a nullable integer. It comes out as a nullable int field in my database

Comment: Checking `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless (your model is `int product_ID`) and its not necessary to set the `cartItem.Customer` and `cartItem.Sku` properties (just the associated `CustomerID` and `SkuID` properties). You have not set a value for `CartID` (you have commented out that line) so an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've made CustomerID in model nullable but also Try making your Customer ID field Nullable in your Database as well or allow the Customer ID field to take null values.

Comment: I've done that. I've tried entering it with a 0 and sending it in with a value of null. In my database, if I expand the columns panel for my cart table, it says my CustomerID is a foreign key with a type of FK, int, null.

Comment: Can you try this and let tell me whats the exact error you are getting ? http://mattrandle.me/viewing-entityvalidationerrors-in-visual-studio/